# Cassandra how can I simulate a join statement

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nosql

I am new to cassandra and am coming from Postgres. I was wondering if there is a way that I can get data from 2 different tables or column family and then return the results. I have this query

```
select p.fullname,p.picture s.post, s.id, s.comments, s.state, s.city FROM profiles as p INNER JOIN Chats as s ON(p.id==s.profile_id) WHERE s.latitudes>=28 AND 29>= s.latitudes AND s.longitudes
    ">=-21 AND -23>= s.longitudes
```

The query has 2 tables: Profiles and Chat and they both share a common field **Chats.id==Proifles.profile_id** it boils down to this basically return all rows where Chat ID is equal to Profiles id. I would like to keep it that way because now updating profiles are simple and would only need to update 1 row per profile update instead of de-normalizing everything and updating thousands of records. Any help or suggestions would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to design tables in way you won't need joins. Best practice is if your table matches exactly the use case it is used for.

Cassadra has a feature called [shared static columns](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refStaticCol.html); this allows you to bind values with partition part of primary key. Thus, you can create "joined" version of table without duplicates.

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    p_id uuid,
    p_fullname text STATIC,
    p_picture text STATIC,
    s_id uuid,
    s_post text,
    s_comments text,
    s_state text,
    s_city text,
    PRIMARY KEY (p_id, s_id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that is perfect